# How to reference a loop variable as a parameter of a method call of an attribute?

Tags: angular

In the html of my component there is like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images; let i=index;" class="m-image-wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-times m-delete-img" (click)="removeImage(i, {{image.docname}})"></i>
</div>
```

At runtime I get console error `Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected`

So how to make the call correctly ?

Comment: you needn't use interpolation if you use `[` `]` or `(` `)`: `(click)="removeImage(i, image.docname)"` see that all inner are "interpretated" as "variables" (removeImage is a function defined in the .ts, i and image.docname are variables defined in the .html). NOTE: If anytime you need use "literal" you use single quotes, e.g. (not about your question) in `[id]="'myID'+i". or is you want to pass some fixed to a function `(click)="doSomething('one')"`

Comment: (click)="removeImage(i, image.docname)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the syntax `{{}}` inside the attributes, so simply change the code to:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images; let i=index;" class="m-image-wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-times m-delete-img" (click)="removeImage(i, image.docname)"></i>
</div>
```

The properties with square brackets and round brackets are already interpolated, instead if you add code outside that properties you should explicitly use the brackets.
Here are some examples:

```
<!-- it shows the value of myVariable inside the div -->
<div [innerHtml]="myVariable"></div>

<!-- it shows the value of myVariable inside the div -->  
<div>{{myVariable}}</div>  

<!-- it execute the method myFunction with myVariable as parameter -->
<div (click)="myFunction(myVariable)">Click here</div>

<!-- it shows the string "myVariable" inside the div -->
<div>myVariable</div>

<!-- it shows the string "myVariable" inside the div -->
<div [innerHtml]="'myVariable'"></div>

<!-- it shows the string "myVariable" inside the div -->
<div innerHtml="myVariable"></div>
```